# IPhone - Not getting Interface Orientation

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to set another position for a UIButton when I change the orientation of my IPhone and I had the idea to implement it inside BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation.
Is this the right way to implement or is there any error on my code? It's not printing these logs.

Code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

if ((interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
    (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight))
{
    NSLog(@"Csantos shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: left or right");
    [adButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 700, 768, 90)];
}
if ((interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) ||
    (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
{
    NSLog(@"Csantos shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: Portrait or UpsideDown portrait");
    [adButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 90)];
}
return YES;
```

}

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code too should work but try putting following code. Change is from **UIDeviceOrientation** to **UIInterfaceOrientation**

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    {
        NSLog(@"Csantos shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: left or right");
        [adButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 700, 768, 90)];
    }
    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
    {
        NSLog(@"Csantos shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: Portrait or UpsideDown portrait");
        [adButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 90)];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation simply specifies what rotations are supported by a UIViewController - nothing more.

You may consider modifying willRotateToInterfaceOrientation which is called just before a rotation is about to begin - to hide background views or other objects, for example.

Then, override didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation which is called after a rotation has just finished - I think this one will be the most important for your setFrame: code.

Comment: Mate, I've just tried with willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation. Both are not working. Is there any other method?

Comment: Did you throw NSLogs in there or similar? Are they not being hit? In your 'Summary' tab, what orientations are you supporting? If you comment out the code in your shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method and replace it so that it matches the orientations listed in the summary and then try. Finally, does this current view controller inherit from anything else that may be overriding it's supported orientations?

Comment: I put some NSLogs in those methods and none of them were thrown. I think they aren't been called. I checked inheritance too, there's nothing that would be a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't undestand, the adButton setFrame works correctly or not and this viewcontroller is root or you have another one. Can't it be that root controller shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation return NO for any orientation?